# How can I use orientDB in MEAN stack

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mean, mean-stack, orientdb

I am working on mean stack. and i want to use orientdb instead of mongodb.
I just want to know how can I replace mongodb with orientDB.
OR 
How can I customize mongoose so that i can use orientDB.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

- MongoDB -> [OrientDB Document Graph database **server**](http://www.orientechnologies.com/download/) (I suppose you want to use the Document-Graph engine of OrientDB) with [orientjs](https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientjs). So you do not customize mongoose, you must replace that driver by orientjs (the official Node driver for OrientDB).
- Express -> Express
- AngularJS -> AngularJs
- Node.js -> Node.js

To get started (assuming you have experience with the EAN-part), first read the [OrienDB Manuel](http://www.orientechnologies.com/docs/last/) and start "playing" with OrientDB, using the web based interface, called OrientDB Studio. A excellent introduction on Graph Databases is [Graph Databases The Definitive Book on Graph Databases](http://graphdatabases.com/) which can be downloaded for free. After that it should be easy to integrate it with Node.js using orientjs. To get started with AngularJS i highly recommend the Udemy courses ["Javascript: Understanding the Weird Parts"](https://www.udemy.com/understand-javascript/) and ["Learn and Understand AngularJS"](https://www.udemy.com/learn-angularjs).

**UPDATE**: [oriento driver](https://github.com/codemix/oriento) is deprecated, the official JavaScript client is now [orientjs](https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientjs). This driver is maintained by Orient Technologies itself.

Comment: Thanks Mr. rmuller ! for reply. Because i am new in this development stack. can you elaborate more your answer. or provide some guideline for this task.

Comment: See my updated answer. If this answer is ok for you, you should "accept" it. This is how SO works.